# Warning message that giant component of disconnected graph is itself disconnected

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I'm a bit confused here, I extracted the giant component of a disconnected graph using the following code.

```
function(graph) {
  cl <- clusters(graph)
  induced.subgraph(graph, which(cl$membership == which.max(cl$csize)))
}
```

But running code like this in RStudio gives me frequent errors such as

```
is_connected(ngo.giant)
[1] TRUE
centr_clo(ngo.giant)$centralization
[1] 0.003214897
Warning message:
In centr_clo(ngo.giant) :
  At centrality.c:2784 :closeness centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs
temp<-centr_eigen(ngo.giant,directed=T)
Warning message:
In centr_eigen(ngo.giant, directed = T) :
  At centrality.c:344 :graph is directed and acyclic; eigenvector centralities will be zeros
```

Is there a reason this is happening? Apologies if this code is too vague

Comment: Your code is not vague, but your problem is. I tried this with a number of randomly generated graphs and never encountered this problem.  Please try to give an example that exhibits this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I just received that warning and I noticed that is due to my graph is directed, so some paths can only be walked in one direction and some nodes are "disconected" from another ones.

```
test <- data.frame(source=c('a', 'a'), target=c('b', 'c'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(test, directed=TRUE)
igraph::closeness(g)

        a         b         c 
0.5000000 0.1666667 0.1666667 
Warning message:
In igraph::closeness(g) :
  At centrality.c:2784 :closeness centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs
```

Likewise, if you use the argument `mehtod='all'` in `closeness`, your graph will be considered as an undirected one.